# How can I change the variable that I enter to an integer from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to store an integer in `x` or `y` that `gets` returned as a string:

```
def add(a, b)
  puts "Adding #{a} + #{b}"
  a + b
end

def sub(a, b)
  puts "subtracting #{a} - #{b}"
  a - b
end

def mult(a, b)
  puts "multiplying #{a} * #{b}"
  a * b
end

def div(a, b)
  puts "dividing #{a} / #{b}"
  a / b
end

x = STDIN.gets.chomp
y = STDIN.gets.chomp
puts add(x,y)
```

The response that I get from the program is:

```
23
43
Adding 23 + 43
2343
```

Comment: The problem is that [`gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) *ONLY* returns a string. It has no concept of anything but a string, nor does the console, which `gets` reads from by default. It's up to you to make that value be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an integer with `to_i`:

```
x = gets.to_i
y = gets.to_i
puts add(x,y)
```

Note that there is no need to use `STDIN.gets` as long as you haven't passed any command line arguments, since `gets` reads from `STDIN` by default.